# MVC different models errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have trying to use a MetadatType model, but getting an error:

.edmx model/order.cs:

```
  public partial class ORDER
  {
    public int Order_Number { get; set; }
    public string Order_Type { get; set; } 
  }
```

metadatatype model:

```
 MetadataType(typeof(ORDERMetadata))]
 public partial class ORDER
{
// Note this class has nothing in it.  It's just here to add the class-level attribute.
 }

public class ORDERMetadata
{   
[Display(Name = "Order Number")]
public Nullable<int> Order_Number { get; set; }  

[Display(Name = "Order Type")]
public string Order_Type { get; set; }

}
```

Controller:

```
    List<ORDERMetadata> result = db.ORDERS.
                                     Where(p => p.Order_Number == id).
                                     Select(x => new ORDERMetadata
                                     {                                             
                                        Order_Number = x.Order_Number,
                                        Order_Type = x.Order_Type

                                     }).ToList();
```

Error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Mvc5_Whitby.Models.ORDERMetadata]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Mvc5_Whitby.Models.ORDERMetadata'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted you view but it must have

```
@model Mvc5_Whitby.Models.ORDERMetadata
```

but you are passing it a collection (the result of your query). Either change the query to return a single item (e.g. `.FirstOrDefault()`, not `.List()`) or change the view to

```
@model List<Mvc5_Whitby.Models.ORDERMetadata>
```

depending on what you want

Answer (score 1):

In the top of your view you probably have this:

```
 @model Mvc5_Whitby.Models.ORDERMetadata
```

When you probably want this, to match what you are passing to the view:

```
 @model IEnumerable<Mvc5_Whitby.Models.ORDERMetadata>
```